# How do I keep heavy rain from draining into my house?

Tags: windows, leak, drainage, rain

The west side of our house is 2 stories high. We have 3 window wells on that side of the house. When we get heavy rains from the west blowing against the house, lets say 3 inches in an hour.  The water can't run away quickly enough and it runs into the basement. My wife wants to put another gutter on that side just above the basement windows to move that rain away.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and added a length of corrugated tubing to my existing downspouts.

What was happening is that the water came down the downspouts too close to the house. It did not have time to soak into the ground and pooled around the foundation. So using some black corrugated pipe and the right adapters got that water 5-10 feet from the house.

It is very low cost, just get some of the black pipe, the right adapters to attach to your downspouts, and sheet metal screws.

Answer (score 1):

Diversion of water as discussed in other answers is a great idea.

You may also consider [window well covers](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Shape-Products-42-in-x-14-in-x-15-in-Thick-Strong-Elongated-Bubble-4213EBT/202936301#.Uhf1bpKKK8A)

[image: window well covers]

They come in a variety of shapes and sizes and divert the bulk of precipitation away from the well and about 2 feet away from the foundation - often enough to avoid seepage.

P.S. They also are a safety feature, reducing the risk of kids/pets falling into the wells.

Answer (score 0):

*Three* inches per hour!  That's close to a lake being dropped on your house!

A gutter above the windows would help.  So would an awning.  Both have disadvantages, like limiting the light into the windows.

Does heavy rain occur frequently?  Or is it just during, say, a hurricane?  Maybe you could put a big tarp—supported like a tent over the west wall— during a storm?

A more permanent idea would be to extend the roof out and make a very deep eave.

---

Addendum:

Since this is the high open side of the house, extreme eaves might help and might look quite cool, but might introduce structural issues in the case of high winds.

What do you think of this kind of solution?:
[image]
Of course it should extend well beyond the window wells and by putting it somewhat high, you could balance the amount of light between summer and winter, so that high summer sun puts the windows in shade and low winter sun streams right in.

Comment: This is a ranch and the roof faces N/S.. So the east and west end are just the peak ends. I build tille sheds over the window wells but when the rains come things seem to get overwelmed. Onve evry 2 years. I have two insurance claims so far. This one is on me

Comment: @ScottRoy:  I have amended my answer with another idea.